# Solving a system of second order differential equations by using Cauchy's formula for repeated integration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve the following system of differential equations:

$$ { d^2f(x) \over dx^2 } =   { e^xg(x) \over 4 } \tag 1$$
$$ { d^2g(x) \over dx^2 } = - { e^xf(x) \over 4 } \tag 2$$

This can be rewritten as one fourth-order differential equation which I don't know how to solve. Because of that, I tried to convert these equations into a single third-order differential equation. However, I am very sure I am doing something wrong.

The goal is to determine the expression for $f(x)$. All of the boundary conditions are non-zero constants. I started by integrating equation $(1)$:

$$ \int _0 ^x { d^2f(t) \over dt^2 } dt = 
   \int _0 ^x  { e^tg(t) \over 4 } dt \tag 3 $$

which led to:

$${ df(x) \over dx } - { df(0) \over dx } =
\int _0 ^x  { e^tg(t) \over 4 } dt \tag 4 $$

After this step, I integrated equation $(4)$ and obtained:

$$\int _0 ^x { df(t) \over dt } dx - 
  { df(0) \over dx } \int _0 ^x dt=
  \int _0 ^x\int _0 ^t  { e^mg(m) \over 4 } dm dt \tag 5 $$

The above equation can be rewritten as:

$$f(x) - f(0)-{ df(0) \over dx } x=
  \int _0 ^x\int _0 ^t  { e^mg(m) \over 4 } dm dt \tag 6 $$

I used Cauchy's formula for repeated integration to write:

$$ \int _0 ^x(x-m){ e^mg(m) \over 4 }dm =
  \int _0 ^x\int _0 ^t  { e^mg(m) \over 4 } dm dt \tag 7 $$

I reformulated equation $(6)$ as:

$$ f(x) - f(0)-{ df(0) \over dx } x= \int _0 ^x(x-m){ e^mg(m) \over 4 }dm \tag8$$

My guess is that I made a mistake in the following step. I differentiated the above equation with respect to $x$ and wrote down:

$${ df(x) \over dx } - { df(x) \over dx }\Bigg|_{x=0} = (x-x){ e^xg(x) \over 4 }=0 \tag 9$$

I hoped to obtain an expression for $g(x)$ in terms of $f(x)$ and its derivatives so I can plug that into equation $(2)$, and then solve that differential equation to obtain the final expression for $f(x)$. However, from equation $(9)$, $f(x)$ is a linear function which I am very sure is not correct.

To summarize, I am trying to determine the general solutions of the system of differential equations $(1)$ and $(2)$. I would appreciate your help in doing that.

Comment: Replace $f(x)=u(e^{x/2})$, $g(x)=v(e^{x/2})$, then combine $z(s)=u(s)+iv(s)$ and insert, and you should get a Bessel-like equation. This then can generally not be simplified further.

Comment: And indeed, the complexification alone is good enough for [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=z%27%27%28x%29%2Bi*exp%28x%29*z%3D0) to give a solution in Bessel functions. Now I do not know how easy it is to extract real and imaginary part of $$f(x)+ig(x)=z(x) = c_1 J_0(\sqrt{2}(1+i) e^{x/2}) + c_2 K_0(\sqrt{2}(1-i) e^{x/2}).$$ $J_n$ Bessel of first kind, $K_n$ modified Bessel of second kind.

Comment: Assuming $e^{x/2} = s$, I get the following two differential equations: $$ s^2 {d^2u(s)\over ds^2} +s {du(s)\over ds} -s^2v(s)=0 $$  $$ s^2 {d^2v(s)\over ds^2} +s {dv(s)\over ds} +s^2u(s)=0 $$ which I rewrote as  $$ s^2 {d^2Z(s)\over ds^2} +s {dZ(s)\over ds} -s^2 \bar Z(s)=0 $$ by assuming $z(s)=u(s)+iv(s)$ and $Z(s)=(z(s)-u(s))+iu(s)$. How did you convert this equation to $Z''(x)+i\cdot e^x Z(x)=0$ (which I notice you wrote into WolframAlpha)? Substitution $s=e^x$ did not work for me. Thank you for the fast reply 
@LutzLehmann.

Comment: The last term is $s^2(-v+iu)=is^2(u+iv)=is^2Z$, there is no conjugate. Now rotate $s$ into the diagonal to get a Bessel equation.

Comment: I see now. Thank you a lot! :D